# LINQ and removing duplicates from an array of objects

Tags: linq, distinct

I'm trying to de-dupe an array of objects using two columns where the second column is a Dictionary. Best way to describe this is to show some code:

```
    class MyClass
    {
        public int ID;
        public Dictionary<int, int> Dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    }
```

And now to create some objects:

```
        List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
        MyClass mc1 = new MyClass();
        list.Add(mc1); mc1.ID = 1; mc1.Dict.Add(1, 1);

        MyClass mc2 = new MyClass();
        list.Add(mc2); mc2.ID = 1; mc2.Dict.Add(1, 1);

        MyClass mc3 = new MyClass();
        list.Add(mc3); mc3.ID = 1; mc3.Dict.Add(1, 2);

        MyClass mc4 = new MyClass();
        list.Add(mc4); mc4.ID = 2; mc4.Dict.Add(1, 1);
```

What I'm looking to accomplish is to distinct by ID and Dict. The results should look like this:

List of MyClass objects (not pretty)

```
1      //MyClass.ID
1,1    //MyClass.Dictionary

1
1,2

2
1,1
```

Notice that one of the objects was dropped from the original list because it had a duplicate ID and Dict (dictionary values). I've been playing around with alternate versions of:

```
        var s = from p in list
                 group p by p.ID into group1
                 from group2 in
                     (from p in group1 group p by p.Dict)
                 group group2 by group1.Key;
```

but just haven't had any luck. Appreciate any insight folks might have on solving this problem.

PS - I'm not changing the rules but I believe a GROUP BY and a SELECTFIRST will be cleaner than a DISTINCT with its extra code for a Comparer. A pat on the back for anyone who can figure this out using GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference types you should add `equality comparer` in order to do what you want. Add the following class:

```
public class MyClassComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyClass>
    {
        public bool Equals(MyClass left, MyClass right)
        {
            if (left == null && right == null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (left == null || right == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (left.ID == right.ID)
            {
                if (left.Dict == null && right.Dict == null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                if (left.Dict == null || right.Dict == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if (left.Dict.Count != right.Dict.Count)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                foreach(var key in left.Dict.Keys)
                {
                    if(!right.Dict.ContainsKey(key))
                        return false;

                    if (left.Dict[key] != right.Dict[key])
                     return false;
                }

                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(MyClass author)
        {
            return (author.ID).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

And use that comparer in `Distinct` override:

```
List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
MyClass mc1 = new MyClass();
list.Add(mc1); mc1.ID = 1; mc1.Dict.Add(1, 1);

MyClass mc2 = new MyClass();
list.Add(mc2); mc2.ID = 1; mc2.Dict.Add(1, 1);

MyClass mc3 = new MyClass();
list.Add(mc3); mc3.ID = 1; mc3.Dict.Add(1, 2);

MyClass mc4 = new MyClass();
list.Add(mc4); mc4.ID = 2; mc4.Dict.Add(1, 1);


var result = list.Distinct(new MyClassComparer()).ToList();
```

You should improve `GetHashCode` method. It will be your homework :)

Answer (score 0):

Can I have half a pat for the following ? :)

```
var filteredList = list.GroupBy(mc => mc.ID)
                       .SelectMany(gr => gr.Distinct(new MyClassComparer()))
                       .ToList();
```

Comparer:

```
public class MyClassComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyClass>
{
    public bool Equals(MyClass a, MyClass b)
    {
        return a.Dict.Count == b.Dict.Count && !a.Dict.Except(b.Dict).Any();
    }


    public int GetHashCode(MyClass a)
    {
        return a.ID;
    }
}
```